# What is the relationship between local machine hostnames and MySQL hostnames?

Tags: mysql, hostname, mariadb

I have Fedora 19 on my local machine and changed the default hostname to `'my.greathostname'`.

So that means when I am using the terminal my prompt is:

```
[me@my ~]
```

I installed MariaDB.

I created a new user in MariaDB eg `'newuser@my.greathostname'`.

When I try and login to MariaDB with `'mysql -u newuser -p'` and enter password I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So, by default, it is trying to login to `'localhost'` and not `'my.greathostname'`.

Why is it trying to login to `'localhost'` when the hostname of my local machine is `'my.greathostname'`.

The reason I want to change the hostname in MariaDB is just to have a more 'custom' experience.

Comment: If you add "my.greathostname" to /etc/hosts as 127.0.0.1, and then add `-h my.greathostname` to your `mysql` command, it should work. To answer the question, MySQL hostnames are indeed ordinary hostnames - they are nothing special. However, two hostnames that alias to the same IP are different.